# Could not open input file : localhost:8080

Tags: php, windows, localhost

On Windows, to run the PHP web server from the command prompt I type:

```
php -s localhost:80800 -t public
```

And I get this error:

> Could not open input file : localhost:8080

And yet `cmd php test.php` will echo the text. Why?

Comment: PHP is not in itself a web server, try wamp or xampp, which are "stacks" that contain a)pache m)ysql and p)hp, this the "amp" part of the name...

Comment: The correct flag would be uppercase `-S`

Comment: @dbinns66 Incorrect. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 23):

It was just the capital `S`.

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

Now I can see the page in a browser.

I had to [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the right directory ...and public has an *index.php* file.

Answer (score 1):

It will work without using [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)/[WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) or any other external server, as PHP has its own server inbuilt. You have done a mistake in typing **s** in `php -s localhost:80800`.

This command will work - `php -S localhost:80800`.

"s" in the command will be capital, not small...

Answer (score 0):

You can not run localhost using native PHP. You need a web server like CAMP or [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) and configure the port while installing this software.

Comment: what is camp? never heard of it

Comment: This answer is incorrect. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running PHP as a CLI (command-line interface).

As stated, there are [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) stacks to install and configure. I would suggest looking online for one of the many tutorials. To install one, they will take you through the process as well as some of the advanced configuration to secure the installation from unwanted outside access.

Answer (score 0):

PHP itself is not a web server, hence why you cannot just write `php -s localhost:8080 -t public`.

You will need to have a corresponding web server, e.g. Apache, and link this with your PHP, allowing PHP to process the files that Apache will serve on its server.

You may want to use [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) to do this, since it is an easy-to-use bundle for Apache, MySQL (a database system), and PHP.

Download it on [its website](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

try php -S  localhost:8080  It's Will work but capital S not The Small one i mean