# php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public not works

Tags: symfony4

When I run this command: `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public` the error is:

```
Could not open input file: 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I'm using `symfony 4`, when I lunch the server with the command `php bin/console server:run` it works, but with command `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public` it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show the exact error, that you have? Also, what OS do you use? What version of `PHP` do you use?

Comment: this is the error Could not open input file: 127.0.0.1:8000, and I use window, php 7.2

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110674/could-not-open-input-file-localhost8080 he had the same error because of invalid option in the command. are you sure that you use English letter in `-S` ? :trollface:

Comment: also, did you tried to update your `php v7.2` to the latest release of 7.2 (i.e. 7.2.24)?

Comment: one more question. do you have any network interface on your PC (i.e. LAN, WIFI)?

Comment: effectively it's due to english letter in -S. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that you found the root cause ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`, which is literally the same, but... who knows ;)

There is also an option to run `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public`, but in if your PC connected to the internet directly, your "web server" will be accessible from the internet.

And, just in case, if you will see error like this: `Directory public does not exist.` that will mean that you have run the command in the wrong folder. `-t public` means that you need to run the command in the folder which **contain** the `public` folder.

Answer (score 1):

May be stupid question but: Why would you launch the server with the php embeded server when the symfony one is working ?

Otherwise even if you don't show the error, I suspect you just need to launch the php server using admin permission, I just faced a similar issue with drupal last day.

Just do : `sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`

And be sure to write the command inside the good directory, otherwise your localhost folder might not be the good one, this might be your issue too.

Comment: he is on Windows ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in php server, point yourself in the root of your project and execute:
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public

If you did not set good files and folders permissions, use the same procedure just run it with SUDO:
sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public

It is important to place yourself in the root of the project while you executing this command!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to define both document_root and router

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public public/index.php
```

Where -t public defines the document_root to be public directory

And public/index.php defines the router script, and all request will be passed to script (normally defined by mod_rewrite in apache.